# Force requests to use IPv4 / IPv6

Tags: python, python-requests, network-programming, ipv6, ipv4

How to force the `requests` library to use a specific internet protocol version for a get request? Or can this be achieved better with another method in Python? I could but I do not want to use `curl`…

Example to clarify purpose:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://my-dyn-dns-service.domain/?hostname=my.domain',
                 auth = ('myUserName', 'my-password'))
```

Answer (score 33):

I've found a minimalistic solution to force urrlib3 to use either ipv4 or ipv6. This method is used by urrlib3 for creating new connection both for Http and Https. You can specify in it any AF_FAMILY you want to use.

```
import socket
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection as urllib3_cn
    
   
def allowed_gai_family():
    """
     https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/util/connection.py
    """
    family = socket.AF_INET
    if urllib3_cn.HAS_IPV6:
        family = socket.AF_INET6 # force ipv6 only if it is available
    return family

urllib3_cn.allowed_gai_family = allowed_gai_family
```

Comment: Nice solution! And it also can be used to force IPv4 simply by changing the function to `def allowed_gai_family(): return socket.AF_INET`

Comment: The question if for requests not urrlib3

Comment: @PedroLobito requests _uses_ urllib3

Comment: To just force IPv4 always, `requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6 = False` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 25):

You can use this hack to force `requests` to use IPv4:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6 = False
```

(This was submitted as a comment by Nulano and I thought it deserved to be a proper answer).

Comment: Most concise solution, though it configures it globally.

Answer (score 21):

This is a hack, but you can monkey-patch getaddrinfo to filter to only IPv4 addresses:

```
# Monkey patch to force IPv4, since FB seems to hang on IPv6
import socket
old_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
def new_getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs):
    responses = old_getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs)
    return [response
            for response in responses
            if response[0] == socket.AF_INET]
socket.getaddrinfo = new_getaddrinfo
```

Comment: Amazing.  Fixes my googleapiclient error: "httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com"

Answer (score 6):

I've written a runtime patch for `requests`+`urllib3`+`socket` that allows passing the required address family optionally and on a per-request basis.

Unlike other solutions there is no monkeypatching involved, rather you replace your imports of `requests` with the patched file and it present a `request`-compatible interface with all exposed classes subclassed and patched and all “simple API” function reimplemented. The only noticeable difference should be the fact that there is an extra `family` parameter exposed that you can use to restrict the address family used during name resolution to `socket.AF_INET` or `socket.AF_INET6`. A somewhat complicated (but mostly just LoC intensive) series of strategic method overrides is then used to pass this value all the way down to the bottom layers of `urllib3` where it will be used in an alternate implementation of the `socket.create_connection` function call.

*TL;DR* usage looks like this:

```py
import socket

from . import requests_wrapper as requests  # Use this load the patch


# This will work (if IPv6 connectivity is available) …
requests.get("http://ip6only.me/", family=socket.AF_INET6)
# … but this won't
requests.get("http://ip6only.me/", family=socket.AF_INET)

# This one will fail as well
requests.get("http://127.0.0.1/", family=socket.AF_INET6)

# This one will work if you have IPv4 available
requests.get("http://ip6.me/", family=socket.AF_INET)

# This one will work on both IPv4 and IPv6 (the default)
requests.get("http://ip6.me/", family=socket.AF_UNSPEC)
```

Full link to the patch library (~350 LoC): https://gitlab.com/snippets/1900824

Answer (score 3):

I took a similar approach to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33046939/5059062, but instead patched out the part in `socket` that makes DNS requests so it **only** does IPv6 or IPv4, for **every** request, which means this can be used in `urllib` just as effectively as in `requests`.

*This might be bad if your program also uses unix pipes and other such things, so I urge caution with monkeypatching.*

```
import requests
import socket
from unittest.mock import patch
import re

orig_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
def getaddrinfoIPv6(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host=host, port=port, family=socket.AF_INET6, type=type, proto=proto, flags=flags)

def getaddrinfoIPv4(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host=host, port=port, family=socket.AF_INET, type=type, proto=proto, flags=flags)

with patch('socket.getaddrinfo', side_effect=getaddrinfoIPv6):
    r = requests.get('http://ip6.me')
    print('ipv6: '+re.search(r'\+3>(.*?)</',r.content.decode('utf-8')).group(1))

with patch('socket.getaddrinfo', side_effect=getaddrinfoIPv4):
    r = requests.get('http://ip6.me')
    print('ipv4: '+re.search(r'\+3>(.*?)</',r.content.decode('utf-8')).group(1))
```

and without `requests`:

```
import urllib.request
import socket
from unittest.mock import patch
import re

orig_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
def getaddrinfoIPv6(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host=host, port=port, family=socket.AF_INET6, type=type, proto=proto, flags=flags)

def getaddrinfoIPv4(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    return orig_getaddrinfo(host=host, port=port, family=socket.AF_INET, type=type, proto=proto, flags=flags)

with patch('socket.getaddrinfo', side_effect=getaddrinfoIPv6):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ip6.me')
    print('ipv6: '+re.search(r'\+3>(.*?)</',r.read().decode('utf-8')).group(1))

with patch('socket.getaddrinfo', side_effect=getaddrinfoIPv4):
    r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://ip6.me')
    print('ipv4: '+re.search(r'\+3>(.*?)</',r.read().decode('utf-8')).group(1))
```

Tested in 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

This is totally untested and will probably require some tweaks, but combining answers from [Using Python “requests” with existing socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665064/using-python-requests-with-existing-socket-connection) and [how to force python httplib library to use only A requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540749/how-to-force-python-httplib-library-to-use-only-a-requests), it looks like you should be able to create an IPv6 only socket and then have requests use that for its connection pool with something like:

```
try:
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
except ImportError:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection

class MyHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):
    def connect(self):
        print("This actually called called")
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port,0,0))
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self._tunnel()

requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnection = MyHTTPConnection
```

Comment: Sorry, I still get an IPv4 answer. I tried `print(requests.get('https://icanhazip.com').text)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to anything with ipv6 at the moment; I did add a print statement and a connect statement just to make sure I didn't miss something with how one goes about monkeypatching the HTTPConnection object

Comment: Ok, I tried it again. The connect method is not called.

Comment: I removed the last 3 parameters of `self.sock.connect(self.host, self.port,0,0)` and tried `MyHTTPConnection('icanhazip.com').request('GET', '/')` directly. Then the method is invoked, but an error is returned: `TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET6 address must be tuple, not str`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to use double parens (one for the call, one for the tuple)

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'

Comment: @1a1a11a  Hmm... in one of the answers I cribbed off of, they did mention that you needed a fairly new version of requests (although that was a couple years old answer IIRC) to get the request.packages bit ... what version of requests are you using?   I just did a pip install and got 2.9.1 and that had requests.packages

Answer (score 1):

After reading the previous answer, I had to modify the code to force IPv4 instead of IPv6. Notice that I used socket.AF_INET instead of socket.AF_INET6, and self.sock.connect() has 2-item tuple argument.

I also needed to override the HTTP**S**Connection which is much different than HTTPConnection since `requests` wraps the httplib.HTTPSConnection to verify the certificate if the `ssl` module is available.

```
import socket
import ssl
try:
    from http.client import HTTPConnection
except ImportError:
    from httplib import HTTPConnection
from requests.packages.urllib3.connection import VerifiedHTTPSConnection

# HTTP
class MyHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):
    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self._tunnel()

requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnection = MyHTTPConnection
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool.ConnectionCls = MyHTTPConnection

# HTTPS
class MyHTTPSConnection(VerifiedHTTPSConnection):
    def connect(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self._tunnel()
        self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)

requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnection = MyHTTPSConnection
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.VerifiedHTTPSConnection = MyHTTPSConnection
requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool.ConnectionCls = MyHTTPSConnection
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, with the caveat that it results in `InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning` when running over https

Answer (score 0):

Based on Yuri's answer, here are simple get and set ip version function that work with requests.
Usage:

```
import requests
set_ip_version(6)

requests.get(...)
set_ip_version(4)
```

Source:

```
import sockets
import requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection


def get_ip_version():
    # type: () -> Optional[int]
    ip_version = requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.allowed_gai_family()
    if ip_version == socket.AF_INET6:
        return 6
    elif ip_version == socket.AF_INET:
        return 4
    else:
        return None


def set_ip_version(ip_version: int = 6):
    # type: (str) -> bool
    """
    Sets preferred IP protocol version to use in requests / ofunctions
    Attention: this propagates
    By default, AF_INET6 is used which preferes IPv6 but fallbacks to IPv4
    """
    if ip_version == 4:

        def allowed_gai_family():
            return socket.AF_INET

    elif ip_version == 6:

        def allowed_gai_family():
            if requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.HAS_IPV6:
                return socket.AF_INET6
            return socket.AF_INET

    else:
        return False

    requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection.allowed_gai_family = allowed_gai_family
    return True
```

These functions exist in ofunctions.network library, installed with `pip install ofunctions.network`. You can then call them with

```
from ofunctions.network import set_ip_version

set_ip_version(6)
```