# golang force net/http client to use IPv4 / IPv6

Tags: go, web-crawler

I' using go1.11 net/http and want to decect if a domain is ipv6-only.

#### What did you do?

I create my own DialContext because want I to detect if a domain is ipv6-only. code below

```golang
package main
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)
func ModifiedTransport() {
    var MyTransport = &http.Transport{
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: false,
            Control: func(network, address string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
                if network == "ipv4" {
                    // I want to  cancel connection here client.Get("http://myexample.com") return a non-nil err.
                    return errors.New("you should not use ipv4")
                }
                return nil
            },
        }).DialContext,
        MaxIdleConns:          100,
        IdleConnTimeout:       90 * time.Second,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }
    var myClient = http.Client{Transport: MyTransport}
    resp, myerr := myClient.Get("http://www.github.com")
    if myerr != nil {
        fmt.Println("request error")
        return 
    }
    var buffer = make([]byte, 1000)
    resp.Body.Read(buffer)
    fmt.Println(string(buffer))
}
func main(){
    ModifiedTransport();
}
```

I do not now how to close the request even when I can get into `network == "ipv4"`.

#### addition

Python can solve the question via [Force requests to use IPv4 / IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046733/force-requests-to-use-ipv4-ipv6). I do not know how to do it in golang. Could someone one help me?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

The `network` passed to the `Control` function is either `tcp4` for an IPv4 connection or `tcp6` for an IPv6 connection, if you are making an outgoing TCP connection.

From the comments on [`type Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer):

> ```
>         // Network and address parameters passed to Control method are not
>         // necessarily the ones passed to Dial. For example, passing "tcp" to Dial
>         // will cause the Control function to be called with "tcp4" or "tcp6".
> ```

(In case of non-TCP connection, [other strings](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dial) are possible.)

> Known networks are "tcp", "tcp4" (IPv4-only), "tcp6" (IPv6-only), "udp", "udp4" (IPv4-only), "udp6" (IPv6-only), "ip", "ip4" (IPv4-only), "ip6" (IPv6-only), "unix", "unixgram" and "unixpacket".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But Do you know how to configure http Transport/DialContext to make the Control only receive a ipv6 connection?

Answer (score 2):

Oh. I fixed the problem myself.

We could not configure force ipv6 connection because it is hard coded

```
...
if cm.scheme() == "https" && t.DialTLS != nil {
        var err error
        pconn.conn, err = t.DialTLS("tcp", cm.addr())
        if err != nil {
            return nil, wrapErr(err)
        }
...
```

( [code here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/6c9b655ac1ab99eb2d3f944deb09b0339717f8cc/src/net/http/transport.go#L1250).)

I add a ipv6only flag for transport.go, a getTcpString() and it works.

([diff here](http://www.mergely.com/BHOKmRtc/))

Answer (score 2):

This works for me with go1.17.1:

```golang
var (
    zeroDialer net.Dialer
    httpClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
    }
)

func init() {
    transport := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
    transport.DialContext = func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return zeroDialer.DialContext(ctx, "tcp4", addr)
    }
    httpClient.Transport = transport
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it is no longer working for me. Go 1.21.

Answer (score 0):

I think even when the server is listening on "tcp6", client running net.Dial using "tcp" should work fine - in dual stack setups.

When I ran into this issue, the culprit was /etc/hosts. It had an entry for the host which was mapped to an ipv4 address instead of ipv6 address. This lead to connection refusal.

My test example as follows:

Client Code:

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "hostname:9876")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in net.Dial", err)
        return
    }

    conn.Close()
    fmt.Println("Successful")
}
```

Server Code:

```
package main

import "net"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp6", ":9876")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error in listen", err)
        return
    }

    for {
        _, err := lis.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error in Accept", err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This code should work fine with clean /etc/hosts file on dual stack setups.

Thanks.