# Go http get force to use ipv4

Tags: go, http, get, httpclient, ipv4

I just simply want to have golang http get request to *use ipv4* ***only***.

And the answers from [golang force net/http client to use IPv4 / IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055808/golang-force-net-http-client-to-use-ipv4-ipv6) is not working for me. Moreover, I found the following answer, which is not working for me either:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Create a transport object
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Dial: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            DualStack: false, // This ensures only IPv4 is used
        }).Dial,
    }

    // Create an HTTP client with the custom transport
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }

    // Create an HTTP GET request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://ifconfig.me/", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating request:", err)
        return
    }

    // Send the request using the client
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error sending request:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Handle the response as needed
    // ...
}
```

I'm still getting IPv6 return with it (from https://ifconfig.me/).

Any help please?

Comment: `DualStack` seems deprecated and really only concerns IPv4 fallback if IPv6 is not configured correctly per the documentation. I think you'll need your own [Resolver](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Resolver) that can force IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, I need to control http requests for IPV4 only or IPV6 only. This is my solution:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network string, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return (&net.Dialer{}).DialContext(ctx, netType, addr)
        },
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        ExpectContinueTimeout: 6 * time.Second,
    },
}
resp, err := client.Get("http://yourwebsite")
```

netType I use tcp4 or tcp6

For more information, https://gist.github.com/Integralist/8a9cb8924f75ae42487fd877b03360e2?permalink_comment_id=4863513 will be a good newbie guide.