# How can we force a post request within a session to use ipv6 address. I am having an ipv6 machine and trying to reach a url which supports ipv6

Tags: python, session, post, python-requests, ipv6

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = "sample_ipv6_host.com/path/to/something"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
```

Firstly, I wanted to know if it is picking up ipv4 or ipv6 with post. I checked it via gethostbyname.
i.e.
hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
socket.gethostbyname(hostname)`your text`

This is printing an ipv4 address.
So, now I want to force the POST request to use ipv6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force requests to use IPv4 / IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046733/force-requests-to-use-ipv4-ipv6)

Comment: I checked this post earlier. But I don't see POST being used there. Appreciate if you can let me know how do you I incorporate it into my POST request.

Comment: `requests.get("http://ip6only.me/", family=socket.AF_INET6)`. this is the same for post right?

Comment: s is requests.Session() here and when I tried to use the family keyword, it says unexpected argument 'family'.